# If I notice missed part after manuscript submission, could I be contact the manager of review?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, springer

I submitted a survey paper, but I forget two lines to describe a method.
Should I contact the manager of review ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just write an email to the editor, specifying exactly what was changed/missing.  (Of course, it should be reasonable enough to warrant the extra work for the editor, and, if it got sent out for review already, also for the referees.)

Comment: I upvoted this. It the bracketed requirement isn't met, OP wait for the review phase.